# Javascript for refreshing an image using VS2010

Tags: c#, javascript, html, visual-studio-2010

I have a project the saves images from an IPcamera to a filestream.  I have another project that takes the image from the filestream and saves it as a jpg, then displays the image in a webform.  Here is the C# code for the second project mentioned:

```
namespace PlayVideo 
public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
{

FileStream fs = File.Open(@"location of filestream");



protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string saveTo = @"place to save";
FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

ReadWriteStream(fs, writeStream);

Response.Clear();
Response.TransmitFile("~/images/test.jpg");


}

// readStream is the stream you need to read
// writeStream is the stream you want to write to
private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream) 
{
int Length = 256;
Byte [] buffer = new Byte[Length];
int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer,0,Length);
// write the required bytes
while( bytesRead > 0 ) 
{
    writeStream.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
    bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer,0,Length);
}
readStream.Close();
writeStream.Close();
}
```

I then added a viewer page to display the image and use javascript to refresh the image, here is that code:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  />
<img src="/video.aspx" id="the-image" alt="" />

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        function refreshImage() {
            $("#the-image").attr('src', 'video.aspx');
            setTimeout("refreshImage();", 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout("refreshImage();", 1000);
                        })


</script> 


</div>
</form>
```

My problem is that the image never refreshes.  I've tried placing the javascript in different sections of the html, and even tried a lot of different javascript methods for this found online.  I am now thinking that something is wrong with my C# code part and not the javascript, but I don't know.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like you have an infinite loop in your refreshImage() function.

Comment: I don't know javascript at all, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Remove the setTimeout function call from within the refreshImage() function. setTimeout will delay the call to the function based on the number provided (in milliseconds). With it nested within the function, it would cause a recursive call that has no end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code: http://jsfiddle.net/39yN8/1/

```
// Declaring a function that may be called later.
function refreshImage()
{
    // Get the img DOM element. Only your img tag with 'myIMG' id is caught.
    objIMG = document.getElementById('myIMG');

    // Refresh the image src attribute.
    // There is some trick to change the original URL string to hack the browser cache.
    objIMG.src = objIMG.src.substr(0, objIMG.src.indexOf('&nocache=')); + '&nocache=' + Math.random();
}

$(document).ready(function () // When page is loaded...
{
    // Call refreshImage function every 1000 milliseconds.
    setInterval(refreshImage, 1000);
})
```

Basically, you have some problems with browser cache, so i added a "no-cache" parameter in URL with a random number in order to trick your browser.

Comment: is there a reference that you are supposed to use when you want to use javascript?  I've tried so many different ways that have worked for other people and none are working for me.

Comment: This code should work with your "image" url and can be changed to use the jQuery library. Case in both forms does not work, the problem is probably your C # code. Something like not sending the correct headers as the mimetype.

Comment: @user3634308, Try to open the URL of your image in the browser. If not open, you already have a problem in C # code.

Comment: The image opens, but in order for the image to refresh I have to hit refresh in the address bar and refresh the whole page

Comment: Yes, does it matter that I'm using VS2010?

Comment: Assuming that the image is being created correctly, no matter the server-side language.

Comment: Since the code that saves the latest image is in Page_Load, does this javascript reload that page or does it put the newest image that was saved?  If it's just the newest image and the page never gets loaded again, then that would explain it I guess.  I don't know much about javascript so I don't know if that is what's happening or not.